# Refreshing the screen after entity update from Rest API is not showing latest data?

Tags: cuba-platform

Steps to reproduce -

1. I have updated the entity data using CUBA REST API.
2. I clicked refresh button in browser, it did refresh but the data in entity viewer is still showing old one. So I closed the entity viewer and opened again - it reflects the new changes.

I think the refresh is not working for entity viewer if it is updated by REST API. 
Is it a bug or any work around is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick workaround is to add a `refresh button` to the UI. Please check below screenshots to add the refresh button. I think that serves the purpose.

1. When Creating the Generic UI, click on Show advanced properties.

[image: Advanced]

2. `Show Advanced Properties > Table Actions > refresh`.

[image]

3. Now you can see `Refresh` button in the web UI, so the user can click refresh button rather than loading the page.

[image: final result]

Answer (score 1):

If you mean refreshing the whole page by F5, it doesn't reload your data by the following reason:

- CUBA generic UI is based on Vaadin, which means it stores the state of all components and data displayed on the page in the web server memory.
- When you hit F5, your browser just loads this state from the server to the page.
- In order to reload data from the middleware to the presentation layer, you need to refresh it on the web server, e.g. by reopening the screen.